# How to get, during test, file generated by sbt (resourceGenerators)?

Tags: scala, sbt, code-generation

So I have this setting

```
(resourceGenerators in Test) += Def.task {
  val file = resourceManaged.value / "simplefolder" / "simplefile"
  IO.write(file, "Hello world!")
  Seq(file)
}.taskValue
```

And in some test I have

```
Source.fromResource("simplefolder/simplefile").mkString
```

I see that the file is created inside the `target/scala-*/resource_managed` folder, but still, I cannot using during the test, because that code throws an NullPointerException... What am I doing wrong there?

If the file were not created in the folder `simplefolder` it works, but when created inside another folder inside the `resourceManaged.value` folder, it doesn't work

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: Can you load a non-generated resource file? Maybe it is a problem with the classloader, have you tried forking the tests? You may also play in a REPL that has the classpath of tests using `test:console` to see if you can list all resources.

Comment: Done... I ran sbt test:console. All test classes are there indeed, but the code `Source.fromResource("simplefile").mkString` and it's actually there, it works... but not during test :(

Comment: Were you able to lead a resource manually placed in `src/test/resources`?

Comment: Yes, I can read it normally, if I placed it there manually. BTW, I edited the previous comment, because in the test console, I can actually read the file

Comment: Wait, now is working... maybe I missed something

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229790/discussion-between-alejandro-navas-and-luis-miguel-mejia-suarez).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scope to `Test` throughout

```
val file = (Test / resourceManaged).value / "simplefolder" / "simplefile"
```

since `show Test / managedResourceDirectories` gives

```
.../target/scala-2.13/resource_managed/test
```

noting the `test` directory at the end.

Comment: Tried it, everything with Compile scope, and it worked too, so it was it. Thanks a lot!